# How do I associate my objects to my meshes and other resources?

Tags: architecture, assets

I am creating a simple 3D engine and I've run into a problem.

I have an array of objects

```
[Camera, Player, Player, MonsterA, MonsterB, MonsterA]
```

and a number of mesh files that I need to associate with these game objects

```
camera.obj, male.obj, female.obj, etc.
```

I pass the state of the world (the array of objects) to my renderer, and I would like to render each object with its associated mesh.

My question is: how / where do I tie these game objects to their meshes?

Should I keep them together as game objects?

```
eg. [(Camera, camera.obj), (Player, male.obj), ...]
```

Or should I have some sort of associative structure within my renderer? Or somewhere else entirely? This question also applies to textures as well. Basically, how do I connect the game objects to their assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways to solve this. One way is, yes, to keep the resources attached to the game objects. Each game object would store a handle to its material and its mesh(es).

Another approach is to keep a separate hierarchy/list of scene nodes. Each game object would just hold a reference to the scene node that represents the object visually. The scene node would then be a small object that has just the visual data.

There's then all kinds of ways to structure that data. An instance of a model has a position and other state but the actual resources can be shared by all instances of that model. So you might have your object or scene node contain per-instance state and then refer to a `ModelTemplate` sort of object which in turn refers to a material and meshes. That is, each goblin might have a position and an animation matrix list and a reference to the goblin model, and the goblin model has a reference to the goblin textures and the creature shader and the skeleton structure information.

In general, just do the simplest thing you can that works. Your players don't care how fancy your graphics architecture is. They only care if your game is fun and pretty and doesn't crash or leak memory.

Comment: Thanks for this - and, while I have your attention, thanks for your talk on entity/component systems.

Answer (score 0):

you can group the objects by needed mesh so you can batch the draw commands without needing to swap out the mesh buffer for each object

this eliminates the need for objects to know about how they are drawn